# converting a word from string as function in C

Tags: c, string

How to convert a word from the string and use it as a function name?

For example:

```
//Given string:
char[] givenString = "myGoal 1,2,3,4";

//Function:
void myGoal()
{
    ...
}
```

I want to extract a word (index 0) "myGoal" from givenString, than use it as a function.

I was thinking to use a control flow: else-if or switch:

ex.:

else-if:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char[] word = "myGoal";

if(strcmp(word, givenString[0])
{
   myGoal();
}
```

or switch:

```
#include <stdio.h>


char[] word = givenString[0];

switch(word){
    case "myGoal":
        myGoal();
        break;
}
```

The problem is that I have a large number of functions, so using of control flow looks not elegant.

I`m sure there must be a nice solution for my code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way to *map* from the string to the function.

If you have multiple strings and functions, an array of structures containing the string and a pointer to the function is a common way to solve the problem:

```
struct map_struct
{
    const char *string;
    void (*function)(void);
};

struct map_struct map[] = {
    { "myGoal", &myGoal },
    // TODO: Other strings and functions here...
};
```

Then you iterate (loop) over the array trying to find the corresponding entry, and call the function:

```
(*map[some_valid_index].function)();
```

---

Note that the method above works find if all functions take the exact same arguments and return the exact type.

If you have different functions taking different arguments, then you either need multiple map structure and array, use a chain of `if`/`else` to call the functions explicitly with the correct arguments.

Or you can use a "generic" pointer to pass structures containing the actual arguments (like many C thread libraries work).

Or if all the data you pass are of the same type, then you could use an *array* (possibly dynamically allocated) and pass a pointer to the first element, together with the number of elements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
I use only one string and various number of functions - the code will be same?

Comment: @YuriiZuev If you mean one *input* string then yes that's okay. You must parse out the "function" name from the input string, and then use `strcmp` between the function name and the strings in the array of structures.. When you find a match call the function (as shown) and `break` out of the loop.

Comment: in case that functions receiving deferent values and not all of them are void, how should I set a map_struct?

Comment: @YuriiZuev Then you need to come up with another way. For example by passing a generic `void *` to a structure containing the actual arguments.